# Differential equations/optimal control in AMPL

Tags: math, optimization, mathematical-optimization, differential-equations, ampl

Does someone has an experience in solving differential equations in AMPL? I googled a lot, but no suitable results...

In google groups I've found a simple "hand-made" example, but it doesn't work...

So, this example I found.

Consider this ODE:

```
   x' = -ax + u, x(0) = 0.
```

where a=0.2 is a parameter; x = state variable, between 0 and 9; u = 
input variable, between 0 and 5. You can write this in AMPL as follows 
(using textbook forward Euler):

```
param N := 10; # no. of integration steps 
param dt := 0.01; # integration step size 
param a := 0.2; 
set kset ordered := 0..N; 
var x{kset}, >= 0, <= 9; 
var u{kset}, >= 0, <= 5; 
minimize obj: 0; 
subject to 
c1{k in 1..N}: (x[k] - x[k-1])/dt = -a*x[k-1] + u[k-1]; 
option solver ipopt; 
solve; 
display x, u;
```

The solution gives me zeros for u and x... It is no wonder because of this line

> minimize obj: 0;

As far as I understood we need to represent the problem as a system of algebraic equations, but what will be a goal function in this case???

So, can somebody give any suggestions or proper examples?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid AMPL is not meant to be used for this kind of tasks. As your example shows, you can hijack it and it may even solve some easier problem instances.

[Modelica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelica) (Optimica language extension) or similar languages are more likely to be adequate for your purposes.